# How to pass an input argument when creating an instance of a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

My idea was to implement the following class:

```
class name(object, name):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print name
```

Then the idea was to create two instances of that class:

```
person1 = name("jean")
person2 = name("dean")
```

I know that is not possible, but how can I pass an input argument into an instance of a class?

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible? start from here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Comment: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F - any introductory Python tutorial will cover this kind of basic OOP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - your link redirects to 404, here is the repost: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
>>> class name(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
... 
>>> person1 = name("jean")
>>> person2 = name("dean")
>>> person1.name
'jean'
>>> person2.name
'dean'
>>>
```

Answer (score 75):

The problem in your initial definition of the class is that you've written:

```
class name(object, name):
```

This means that the class inherits the base class called "object", and the base class called "name". However, there is no base class called "name", so it fails. Instead, all you need to do is have the variable in the special `__init__` method, which will mean that the class takes it as a variable.

```
class name(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    print(name)
```

If you wanted to use the variable in other methods that you define within the class, you can assign name to self.name, and use that in any other method in the class without needing to pass it to the method.

For example:

```
class name(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def PrintName(self):
    print(self.name)

a = name('bob')
a.PrintName()
bob
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to do it in correct syntax. Let me give you a minimal example I just did with Python interactive shell:

```
>>> class MyNameClass():
...   def __init__(self, myname):
...       print myname
... 
>>> p1 = MyNameClass('John')
John
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove the `name` param from the class declaration. The `__init__` method is used to pass arguments to a class at creation.

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

me = Person("TheLazyScripter")
print me.name
```

Answer (score 2):

[Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

```
class name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("name: "+name)
```

Somewhere else:

`john = name("john")`

Output:
`name: john`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can!
How about this?

```py
class name(str):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print (name)
# ------
person1 = name("jean")
person2 = name("dean")
print('===')
print(person1)
print(person2)
```

Output:

```
jean
dean
===
jean
dean
```

Answer (score 1):

> *class* **Person**:
>
> > def **init**(self,name,age,weight,sex,mob_no,place):
> >
> > > self.name = str(name)
> > >       self.age = int(age)
> > >       self.weight = int(weight)
> > >       self.sex = str(sex)
> > >       self.mob_no = int(mob_no)
> > >       self.place = str(place)

### Creating an instance to class Person

```
p1 = Person(Muthuswamy,50,70,Male,94*****23,India)

print(p1.name)

print(p1.place)
```

### Output

```
Muthuswamy

India
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a good idea to use different names for things that play different roles in the code.  E.g. as in the following code:

```
class Onoma:
def __init__(self, dummy_name):
    self.name = dummy_name
    print(self.name)
```

Then

```
a = Onoma("MN")
a.name
```

returns

```
'MN'
```